# How to start angularjs app with teamcity

Tags: angularjs, node.js, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I've created a angularjs application with a restful node backend service. I'm using teamcity to build and deploy my application to a windows server my build steps are:

1. npm install -g grunt-cli
2. npm install -g bower
3. npm install
4. bower install
5. grunt build

   ...

my NuGet package looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
    <metadata>
        <id>#ID#</id>
        <version>#VERSION#</version>
        <authors>#AUTHORS#</authors>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>#DESCRIPTION#</description>
    </metadata>

    <files>
        <file src="package.json" target="package.json" />
        <file src="bower.json" target="bower.json" />
        <file src="index.js" target="index.js" />
        <file src="elastic.backend.js" target="elastic.backend.js" />
        <file src="redis.backend.js" target="redis.backend.js" />
        <file src="mongo.backend.js" target="mongo.backend.js" />
        <file src="LocRanks.js" target="LocRanks.js" />
        <file src="PersonTypes.js" target="PersonTypes.js" />
        <file src="Gruntfile.js" target="Gruntfile.js" />
        <file src="app\**\*" target="app" />
        <file src="dist\**\*" target="dist" />
        <file src="services.xml" target="services.xml" />
        <file src="config\**\*" target="config" />
        <file src="lib\**\*" target="lib" />
    </files>
</package>
```

and services.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<services>
  <service id="1" run="C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" args="index.js esrd-dashboard" />
</services>
```

The node backend service starts and is running however even though the dist/ folder has been created and contains the minified app/ contents I have no clue how to start the frontend of the application. grunt serve doesn't work and neither does http-server. How can automate starting my frontend with teamcity.

Comment: Why doesnõt grunt serve work?

Comment: windows doesn't like to install all on grunt serve dependencies so you cant packages and deploy